# Python just let main thread sleep

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

I use time.sleep() in my main thread and want just this thread to sleep. The problem is, that all the other threads I created in the main are sleeping too. One problem might be that they have to access a global variable.
The aim is just to not create too many threads at one time - so I count the running threads and if they are > 200 I want to let the main thread sleep to give the other threads more time.

```
    import requests
import ipaddress
import sys
import threading
import time

loginIndicators = ["username", "user name", "password", "passwort", "log in", "sign in", "anmelden", "signin", "login", "submit", "account", "user", "pass", "id", "authentification", "authentication", "auth", "authorization", "access", "passphrase", "key"]
scancounter = 0

def scan(ip, port, protocol):
    global scancounter
    global file
    try:
        res = requests.get(protocol + "://" + ip.exploded + ":" + port + "/", timeout=1)
    except:
        return
    finally:
        scancounter += 1    

    if res.status_code == 401 or any(indicator in res.text.lower() for indicator in loginIndicators):
        print("Found: " + ip.exploded + ":" + port + " --> " + protocol)
        file.write(protocol + "://" + ip.exploded + ":" + port + "\n")

def output_status(end):
    global scancounter
    if(end):
        time.sleep(3)
    print("Scanned: " + str(int(scancounter / len(ports) / 2)))

try:
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        try:
            nw = ipaddress.ip_network(input("Enter the starting IP address: "))
        except:
            print("Invalid format - expected: IP/prefix")
            sys.exit()

        ports = input("Enter the ports that should be tested: ")

        if ports == "":
            ports = ["80","8080","443"]
        else:
            ports = ports.replace(" ", "")
            ports = ports.split(",")

        file = input("Output file path: ")
        if file != "":
            file = open(file, "a")

        iprange = nw.hosts()

        try:
            skip = input("How many addresses do you want to skip: ")
            if skip == "":
                skip = 0
            for i in range(0, int(skip)):
               next(iprange)
        except: 
            print("You can't skip more addresses than the IP range contains!")
        for ip in iprange:
            for port in ports:
                threading.Thread(target=scan, args=(ip, port, "http",)).start()
                threading.Thread(target=scan, args=(ip, port, "https",)).start()
        threading.Thread(target=output_status, args=(True,)).start()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    threading.Thread(target=output_status, args=(True,)).start()
```

Comment: @9769953 added it

Comment: @9769953 do you need anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you calling `output_status` in the main thread rather than starting a thread for it?

```
threading.Thread(target=output_status, args=(True,)).start()
```

If you did that the sleep would occur on the main thread.

```
output_status(True)
```

Comment: This method is not the problem but the scan method. I create numerous threads of this method in a for loop and at some point it is just too much.

Comment: How many is numerous? Generally, threads are limited by cores, if you create 100 threads and have like 4 cores, only 4 threads will be ran at the time (at best case). In case of Python, threads are limited to 1 at the time basically because of GIL, if you have to create "numerous" threads then you should read about what a thread is and what they are used for again, because even if Python didn't have GIL, you still most likely don't have a server to excuse massive creation of threads.

Comment: I was going to suggest that you should use a worker pool with a job queue such as `multiprocessing.Pool`. But that wouldn't have addressed the main issue in the question that the main thread wasn't sleeping. Rather its child thread was. And even with the `Pool`, it job queue isn't limited either. Which turns the excessive threads into excessive jobs in the work queue. So you end up having to limit the number of jobs or threads with a semaphore anyway.